# Parsing barry SMS backups

Tags: backup, sms, blackberry

I used `barry` to backup all my messages on my BlackBerry Curve 9220. Now I try to restore them, but none of the messages get restored. I've tried it via the GUI as well as `bio` but to no avail. Now I had some important messages there. So, I tried using `btardump` to dump the messages in vFormat but that didn't help either. Is there any way I can read those messages on my computer?

> Ubuntu version: 14.04 LTS

Edit#2:
I did back them up properly. Here are some screenshots:

The Text Messages folder of the backup archive

[image]

The output file from `btardump`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you ruled out the possibility that you didn't back them up properly in the first place? In other words, the restore operation worked perfectly, but nothing was saved, so no messages were restored.